# hibernate onetomany annotation fetch = FetchType.LAZY didn't work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many

I have three tables `A`,`B` and `C`. Table `B` has a foreign key `a_id` reference to table `A`, Table `B` has a foreign key `a_id` reference to table `A`. And my hibernate entity files are as following:

A.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    private long id;
    private String contentA;
    private List<B> bList;
    private List<C> cList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy = "b")
    public List<B> getbList() {
        return bList;
    }

    public void setbList(List<B> bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , mappedBy = "b")
    public List<C> getcList() {
        return cList;
    }

    public void setcList(List<C> cList) {
        this.cList = cList;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content_a", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContentA() {
        return contentA;
    }

    public void setContentA(String contentA) {
        this.contentA = contentA;
    }
}
```

B.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    private long id;
    private String contentB;
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content_b", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContentB() {
        return contentB;
    }

    public void setContentB(String contentB) {
        this.contentB = contentB;
    }

}
```

C.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    private long id;
    private String contentC;
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content_c", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContentC() {
        return contentC;
    }

    public void setContentC(String contentC) {
        this.contentC = contentC;
    }

}
```

the problem is sometimes I just want to get `A` with `List<B>`, in another time I want to get `A` with `List<C>`. Is there any way I can do this by hibernate?

------------------------divide line----------------------

In my real project, I have three entity class: `ChapterEntity` `ChapterTitle1Entity` `ChapterTitle2Entity` `ChapterTitle3Entity`. There is a `private List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList;` in `ChapterEntity`, also `private List<ChapterTitle2Entity> chapterTitle2EntityList;` in `ChapterTitle2Entity`, `private List<ChapterTitle3Entity> chapterTitle3EntityList;` in `ChapterTitle2Entity`.

I just want to get a list of `ChapterEntity` with sublist `List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList`, the lazy load annotation didn't work. the following are my class files

ChapterEntity.java

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-9/6/16
 * Time 11:16 PM
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapter")
public class ChapterEntity {
    private List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList;
    private long id;
    private int sequence;
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "chapterEntity")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public List<ChapterTitle1Entity> getChapterTitle1EntityList() {
        return chapterTitle1EntityList;
    }

    public void setChapterTitle1EntityList(List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList) {
        this.chapterTitle1EntityList = chapterTitle1EntityList;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChapterEntity that = (ChapterEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (sequence != that.sequence) return false;
        if (content != null ? !content.equals(that.content) : that.content != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + sequence;
        result = 31 * result + (content != null ? content.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

ChapterTitle1Entity.java

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-11
 * Time 6:09 PM
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapter_title_1", schema = "tutorial2")
public class ChapterTitle1Entity {
    private long id;
    private int sequence;
    private String content;
//    private long chapterId;
    /**
     * 1:章前测试，2：实际的测试
     */
    private int type;
    private ChapterEntity chapterEntity;
    private List<ChapterTitle2Entity> chapterTitle2EntityList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "chapterTitle1Entity")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public List<ChapterTitle2Entity> getChapterTitle2EntityList() {
        return chapterTitle2EntityList;
    }

    public void setChapterTitle2EntityList(List<ChapterTitle2Entity> chapterTitle2EntityList) {
        this.chapterTitle2EntityList = chapterTitle2EntityList;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_id", nullable = false)
    public ChapterEntity getChapterEntity() {
        return chapterEntity;
    }

    public void setChapterEntity(ChapterEntity chapterEntity) {
        this.chapterEntity = chapterEntity;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

/*
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "chapter_id", nullable = false)
    public long getChapterId() {
        return chapterId;
    }

    public void setChapterId(long chapterId) {
        this.chapterId = chapterId;
    }
*/

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChapterTitle1Entity that = (ChapterTitle1Entity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (sequence != that.sequence) return false;
//        if (chapterId != that.chapterId) return false;
        if (type != that.type) return false;
        if (content != null ? !content.equals(that.content) : that.content != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + sequence;
        result = 31 * result + (content != null ? content.hashCode() : 0);
//        result = 31 * result + (int) (chapterId ^ (chapterId >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + type;
        return result;
    }
}
```

ChapterTitle2Entity.java

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-9/6/16
 * Time 11:16 PM
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapter_title_2")
public class ChapterTitle2Entity {
    private long id;
    private int sequence;
    private String content;
    //    private long title1Id;
    private List<ChapterTitle3Entity> chapterTitle3EntityList;
    private ChapterTitle1Entity chapterTitle1Entity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "title_1_id", nullable = false)
    public ChapterTitle1Entity getChapterTitle1Entity() {
        return chapterTitle1Entity;
    }

    public void setChapterTitle1Entity(ChapterTitle1Entity chapterTitle1Entity) {
        this.chapterTitle1Entity = chapterTitle1Entity;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "chapterTitle2Entity")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public List<ChapterTitle3Entity> getChapterTitle3EntityList() {
        return chapterTitle3EntityList;
    }

    public void setChapterTitle3EntityList(List<ChapterTitle3Entity> chapterTitle3EntityList) {
        this.chapterTitle3EntityList = chapterTitle3EntityList;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

/*
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title_1_id", nullable = false)
    public long getTitle1Id() {
        return title1Id;
    }

    public void setTitle1Id(long title1Id) {
        this.title1Id = title1Id;
    }
*/

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChapterTitle2Entity that = (ChapterTitle2Entity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (sequence != that.sequence) return false;
//        if (title1Id != that.title1Id) return false;
        if (content != null ? !content.equals(that.content) : that.content != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + sequence;
        result = 31 * result + (content != null ? content.hashCode() : 0);
//        result = 31 * result + (int) (title1Id ^ (title1Id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
}
```

ChapterTitle3Entity.java

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-9/6/16
 * Time 11:16 PM
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapter_title_3")
public class ChapterTitle3Entity {
    private long id;
    private int sequence;
    private String content;
//    private long title2Id;
    private ChapterTitle2Entity chapterTitle2Entity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "title_2_id", nullable = false)
    public ChapterTitle2Entity getChapterTitle2Entity() {
        return chapterTitle2Entity;
    }

    public void setChapterTitle2Entity(ChapterTitle2Entity chapterTitle2Entity) {
        this.chapterTitle2Entity = chapterTitle2Entity;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    public int getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(int sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

/*
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title_2_id", nullable = false)
    public long getTitle2Id() {
        return title2Id;
    }

    public void setTitle2Id(long title2Id) {
        this.title2Id = title2Id;
    }
*/

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ChapterTitle3Entity that = (ChapterTitle3Entity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (sequence != that.sequence) return false;
        if (content != null ? !content.equals(that.content) : that.content != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + sequence;
        result = 31 * result + (content != null ? content.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

my DAO layer `ChapterDAO.java`

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.model.dao;

import com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity.ChapterEntity;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-9
 * Time 11:13 PM
 */
@Repository
public class ChapterDAO extends BaseDAO<ChapterEntity> {

    public List<ChapterEntity> chapterEntityList(){
        Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria(ChapterEntity.class, "chapter");
        criteria.createAlias("chapter.chapterTitle1EntityList", "title1List");
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("title1List.sequence"));
        List<ChapterEntity> chapterEntityList = criteria.list();
        return chapterEntityList;
        /*String hql = "from ChapterEntity";
        List<ChapterEntity> chapterEntityList = session().createQuery(hql).list();
        return chapterEntityList;*/
    }

}
```

my service layer `ChapterSvc`

```
package com.hnu.tutorial.service.impl;

import com.hnu.tutorial.model.dao.ChapterDAO;
import com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity.ChapterEntity;
import com.hnu.tutorial.model.entity.ChapterTitle1Entity;
import com.hnu.tutorial.service.dto.ChapterDTO;
import com.hnu.tutorial.service.dto.ChapterTitle1DTO;
import com.hnu.tutorial.service.interfaces.IChapterSvc;
import com.hnu.tutorial.utils.BeanMap;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiqin_zhang@qq.com on 2016-09-10
 * Time 10:59 AM
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class ChapterSvc implements IChapterSvc {

    @Autowired
    private ChapterDAO chapterDAO;

    @Override
    public List<ChapterDTO> chapterDTOList() {
        List<ChapterEntity> chapterEntityList = chapterDAO.chapterEntityList();
        List<ChapterDTO> chapterDTOList = BeanMap.mapList(chapterEntityList, ChapterDTO.class);
        for(ChapterDTO chapterDTO:chapterDTOList){
            List<ChapterTitle1Entity> chapterTitle1EntityList = chapterDTO.getChapterTitle1EntityList();
            for (ChapterTitle1Entity chapterTitle1Entity:chapterTitle1EntityList){
                chapterTitle1Entity.setChapterEntity(null);
            }
        }
        return chapterDTOList;
    }
}
```

Each time when I query the chapter list, I get all the sub list. Even when I set a breakpoint in the end of method `chapterEntityList()` of my service layer, I also get all the sub list. I also tried query a list use hql, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FetchType.EAGER` to `FetchType.LAZY` in your `@OneToMany` annotations. This will casue Hibernate to load a collection only when you directly refer to it.

Comment: I have test but it didn't work. so I think maybe `FetchType.LAZY` is needed to accomplish this, but there may be another configuration also needed.

Comment: Please post your code, where you fetch entities from database.

Comment: if you are using HQL and you want to get `A` with `List<B>` you should do: `SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.bList`

Comment: Thank u very much, I have update my question, and it is the project I have done in reality.

Comment: The thing is that the very act of looking at these sublists in the debbuger causes Hibernate to load them. To check if the sublist was fetched you should use Hibernate.isInitialized() or remove entity from the session with session.evict() before looking atthe debbuger.